# using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, boolean-logic

```
def custom_regularizer(weights, lambda_=0.001, gamma=3.7):
    a = tf.multiply(tf.cast(abs(weights) <= lambda_,dtype=tf.float32),lambda_ * abs(weights))
    b = tf.multiply((tf.cast(lambda_ < abs(weights),dtype=tf.float32) and tf.cast(abs(weights) < gamma * lamdbda_,dtype=tf.float32)),
                    2 * gamma * lambda_ * abs(weights) - weights**2 - lambda_**2 / 2 * (gamma - 1))
    c = tf.multiply(tf.cast(abs(weights) >= (gamma * lambda_),dtype=tf.float32), lambda_**2 * (gamma + 1) / 2)
    scad = a+b+c
return scad
```

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8sxX.png)

I made code based on that picture to make "scad function" with custom regularizer.

However, when we put that function in the kernel_regularizer = of the model, using a 'tf.The error Tensor' as a Python'bool' is not allowed. What is the problem?

Comment: Try using `tf.math.logical_and` and cast the output of that to float instead of Python's `and` when calculating `b`.

Comment: I already solved this problem, but thanks for your answer!